# How does the Model(MVP in android) have access to read and modify common application data?

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp, android-architecture

As I understood in the View need to create a Presenter and in the Presenter need to create Model.
How does the Model(MVP in android) have access to read and modify common application data?

- use static methods and variables to work with shared data?
- to pass the reference to the data through View and Present in Model?
- to create a Model not in Presenter?

Answer (score 0):

The Presenter is the one that handles the data, the view only has to paint what the presenter commands with the data that handles the model and the model is simply your business model. 
The Presenter acts as a controller, manages the model so that the view only has to worry about painting the received data, in this way you decouple the view of the model and you can test in the present all the logic that is handled by unitary tests.

In this link from Antonio Leiva explain the pattern pretty well:

[Model-View-Presenter](https://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/)